# Exclude possibility of Ribbon in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I've sought for a solution everywhere:

I've made a user program (in EXCEL) where the user shouldn't be able to change anything concerning the formatting (colour, width, fonts, comments ... etc. etc.): the user is only capable to see the tables in the (visible) sheets on the screen and the tabs "chooser".
The user can actively only edit in the cells. I use extensively sheet protection, shortcuts, scrollarea and my userdefined contextmenu to achieve what I want. With my +400kB VBAcode.
It works perfect in Excel 2007 (and I think for Excel 2010)!

For the ribbon to not appear I use:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", False)"
```

But not in Excel 2013! I use massively the [ALT]-key for my shortcuts, but when pressing it, the ribbons formatting options appear.

I've seen examples using:

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
```

But it is not a solution as it is always possible for the user get to the  *Autohide ribbon/Show Tabs/Show Tabs and Commands* in the right upper corner.

Is there a way to get "rid" of the ribbon in Excel 2013 and by no means (except VBA) to get it back. Specially the [ALT]-stroke form the user shouldn't be able to call it.

**EDIT**
I've added an image showing a section of what it looks like having NO Quick Access Bar or Ribbon in my EXCEL 2007. There is only the MS titleline, a plein table and some tabs (sheets) to chose.
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, keyboard shortcuts work whether the ribbon is visible or not. To remove the ribbon, you would generally use the CustomUI part of the workbook and the `StartFromScratch` attribute.

Comment: @Rory. When you press ALT and you are not quick enough to press the other key, the ribbon appear! But the StartFromScratch is a solution I'll try out (I don't actually have the 2013 edition on my laptop; I have to get to work to play with it). I'll try it to see if this solution can wipe every trace of ribbon out and the quick access!

Comment: My point was that things like `Ctrl+B` I think will work even if the ribbon isn't visible.

Comment: @Rory. There is no problem using the shortcuts.They work. Also if one use Application.onKey to define them. But what I don't want, is to get the Ribbon or Quick Access to appear at any time for the user. And I saw that happend with my Chief, her using Excel 2013.

Comment: You said you **didn't** want them changing formatting?!

Comment: @Rory. I've shortcuted the use of for example [CTRL]B/I. But that is not the biggest point. The user shouldn't not be able to do anything of what the ribbon.and Quick Acceess offer. That could as well be insert, validation, filtering, sorting, freezing aso. Therefore it shouldn't under any - normal -  curcumstances appear. Hope it is more clear.